# How to define the variable as a matrix in sage?

Tags: matrix, functional-programming, sage

I want to define a function which deals with matrices for example..

If I have a characteristic polynomial of a matrix with me and I want to check the cayley hamilton theorem.. What can be done better?

```
var('x')
f(x)=2x^2+x+3 # this the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (say)
print f(A)# this is what I want as an answer..
```

In the above if I want to replace my x by a matrix what I have to do?

So, ultimate aim is to find define a polynomial which can take matrix 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazingly, apparently this hasn't come up very often despite having already been mentioned [six years ago](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sage-edu/0hPo7pl-G5I/b8JHA4nq6tsJ), so we haven't fixed it.

```
sage: M = matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
sage: g(x) = x^2-5*x-2
sage: g(M)
TypeError: no canonical coercion from Full MatrixSpace of 2 by 2 dense matrices over Integer Ring to Callable function ring with argument x
```

(Doing at least something about this is [Trac 15487](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/15487).)

However, try [using this trick](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzzVbBVyE0sKcqs0IiONtQxitWJNtYxiY3V5OVKA0r56iVnJBYV5OdUaoBE9IpLk4o1Kmx9NQHERRAK&lang=sage).  The problem is only with symbolic expressions, not polynomials.

```
sage: M = matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
sage: f = M.charpoly()
sage: f.subs(x=M)
[0 0] 
[0 0]
```

Edit: in general, try something [like this](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzzVbBVyE0sKcqs0IiONtQxitWJNtYxiY3V5OUK0rMpsQNKB-TnVObl52Ym5gRl5qVrBAcB5dKA4iVxRtol2oZAjoavJgDwGRPn&lang=sage).

```
M = matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
R.<t> = PolynomialRing(SR)
f = t^2+t+1
f(M)
```

Comment: If suppose i want to put some orbitrary polynomial instead of charpoly..and i want to substiture M for x...What should I do? @kcrisman

Comment: Define it as a polynomial, not "expression".  I'll try to update the answer.